# How to find out which part of a c# - code consumes to most computer power to optimize this part?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there)

I wrote an application in c# for the kinect. For some reason the app consumes more than 100 MB in ram and 14 per cent of all processing power.

Without going into detail, are there applications for Visual Studio or external which help me find out where the biggest workload stems from to know where to optimize?

I am talking about extensions or similar that visualize code lines for instance dye those red that are under heavy load and dye those blue that are not executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642569/good-profiler-for-c-sharp-2010 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-sharp-profilers-out-there

Comment: Just pause the debugger a couple of times while it's doing that and see what it's doing.

Comment: Profilers do this stuff.  Look at Ants profiler/memory profile.