# Performance/Memory profiling for a C#/XAML App

Tags: c#, performance, xaml, profiler

I am currently working on a C#/XAML application, I need to do performance profiling to figure out XAML bottlenecks. Any good profilers/tools available?

Comment: Duplicate, seem my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642827/659778).

Answer (score 1):

1. Visual Studio (Performance tools) [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23205) and [How to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx).
2. RedGate [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
3. Telerik [JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx)

The last 2 are good ones, and not free

Comment: Are any tools able identify XAML perf issues?

Comment: @user1542794 not sure what you mean. You can trace memory or CPU performance.

Comment: Would these tools be able to pinpoint problems with the xaml markup? That is where we suspect our bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

[PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) is free tool that is used by the CLR performance team. It is specifically designed for profiling the performance of .NET applications and can do both CPU and memory (managed heap) investigations. A plus is that it doesn't require running an install on a machine to collect performance data. There is an awesome [series of videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial) by Vance Morrison on using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

what app are you developing, WPF, Silverlight or win8? Basiclly the profile tool inside Visual Studio is enough to figure out the bottlenecks.