# Coalescing a tree of named profile samples into a top-down summation

Tags: ruby, profiling

I have an array of arrays of names that could be represented in Ruby like this:

```
samples = [
  %w[a],
  %w[a c],
  %w[a],
  %w[a],
  %w[b],
  %w[b],
  %w[a],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a c d],
  %w[a c d],
  %w[b],
  %w[b c e],
  %w[b c e],
  %w[a c],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a e]
]
```

These are the output of a sampling profiler, where each list of names represents the call stack for a particular sample. I want to display these as a top-down tree of named-values where the value at each node is the sum of hits to that particular call path.

For the above sample input, the output tree should be:

```
root:0
  a:4
    e:4
    c:2
      d:2
  b:3
    c:0
      e:2
```

(I don't want an ASCII output as shown above, but rather a tree structure that represents this.)

What is simple, efficient code that produces this output?
*I have my own solution which I will post as an answer, but which seems to me less than ideal.*

**Edit**: I forgot to include the fact that the tree should be sorted in descending value at each level. I've added sample nodes and changed the output to reflect this.

Comment: Is that Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.something_else ? Thanks

Comment: @NeX Forgive me for not specifying. 1.9.2 is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit] A recursive *Tree* class with functional programming (I use *ostruct* for the sake of simplicity):

```
require 'ostruct'

class Tree < OpenStruct 
  def self.new_from_array(plain)
    Tree.new(:node => "root", :count => 0, :children => children_from_array(plain))
  end

  def self.children_from_array(plain)
    plain.group_by(&:first).map do |node, group|
      terminal, leaves = group.map { |xs| xs.drop(1) }.partition(&:empty?)
      Tree.new(:node => node, :count => terminal.size, :children => children_from_array(leaves))
    end.sort_by(&:count).reverse    
  end

  def inspect(indent=0)
    node_info = " "*indent + "#{self.node}: #{self.count}" 
    ([node_info] + self.children.map { |tree| tree.inspect(indent+2) }).join("\n")
  end  
end
```

Example:

```
>> Tree.new_from_array(samples)
=>
root: 0
  a: 4
    e: 4
    c: 2
      d: 2
  b: 3
    c: 0
      e: 2
```

You can customize `inspect` to fit your visualization needs.

Answer (score 2):

Does this get you started?

```
>> samples.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |arr, h| h[arr] += 1 } 
#=> {["a"]=>4, ["a", "c"]=>2, ["b"]=>3, ["a", "c", "d"]=>2, ["b", "c", "e"]=>2}
```

Once you have the counts for each array, you can start grouping them using `group_by` or something similar.

Note that if you are on 1.8 you'll have to use `inject` instead of `each_with_object`:

```
>> samples.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, arr| h[arr] += 1 ; h} 
#=> {["a"]=>4, ["a", "c"]=>2, ["b"]=>3, ["a", "c", "d"]=>2, ["b", "c", "e"]=>2}
```

Sorry, I'm leaving now so don't have much more time... If this is not enough post a comment and I'll try to answer later.

Comment: I think that grouping is not enough. In order to make a tree you need something a little more complex.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Interestingly, `samples.group_by{|o|o}.map{|x,y|[x,y.length]}` is about 25% faster than `Hash(0).tap{|h| samples.each{|c| h[c]+=1 }` (where `tap/each` is a smidgeon faster than `each_with_object`).

Comment: @NeX: I never said it's a complete solution, it was just to get OP started.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a far better answer than my first, inspired by @MichaelKohl:

```
require 'pnode' # see below
root = PNode.new("root",0)
samples.group_by{ |o| o }.each do |callstack,instances|
  n = root; last_index = callstack.length-1
  callstack.each_with_index do |name,i|
    n = n[name]
    n.time += instances.length if i==last_index 
  end
end

root.sort!
puts root

# pnode.rb
class PNode
  attr_accessor :name, :time, :parent, :kids
  def initialize(name,time=0,parent=nil)
    @name, @time, @parent = name, time, parent
    @kids = []; @by_name = {}
  end
  def []( name )
    kids << (@by_name[name] = self.class.new(name,0,self)) unless @by_name[name]
    @by_name[name]
  end
  def sort!
    @kids.each(&:sort!).sort_by!{ |n| [-n.time,n.name] }
    self
  end
  def to_s(lv=0)
    [ "#{'..'*lv}#{name}:#{time}", *kids.map{|k| k.to_s(lv+1) } ].join("\n")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To try to answer the question, can't you just build a tree by inserting each sample one at a time? and sort them as you go or at the end?

If you don't mind some additional suggestions, illustrated by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525758/function-profiling-woes-visual-studio-2010-ultimate/5560023#5560023) :

- If you're worried about efficiency because you've got jillions of stack samples, if you just randomly use about 100 of them, you'll get plenty enough information for finding bottlenecks. [Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387895/if-profiler-is-not-the-answer-what-other-choices-do-we-have/4390868#4390868)
- The problem with building a tree whose root is the main program is that there may not actually be a "hot path", even if there's a bona fide hot bottleneck, as that example shows. The solution is to allow the user to pick any routine as the "root", such as `c` in your example, which is active 6/17 of the time.
- When you get each stack sample, you not only get a routine name, but a line number. If the user is interested in a "hot" routine (that appears on many samples), they're going to want to know where inside the routine the time was spent. That information is in those line numbers. So I suggest *lines*, not *routines* be your basic unit of tree-building.
- Suppose there is recursion, so the same routine/line can appear more than once in a sample. What do you do? Well, regardless of how many times a routine/line appears in a sample, it is still only one sample. The cost of a line is just the fraction of samples that contain it, with or without recursion, because suppose you are taking samples every 10ms. If that routine/line could be made to take no time (say, by removing or avoiding it), all the samples containing it would disappear from the total, recursion or no. 
   So if I'm building a butterfly view focussed on a single line, I only need to show one layer of calls below it, and one above. So I build a local down-tree showing just the lines that appeared below the focus (in the samples), and likewise for the up-tree, regardless of recursion.
- In my experience I do a lot of this by hand, and automation would help, but once I want to investigate a particular hot line, I want to be able to see *individual stack samples* going through that line. The reason is I don't care about the measurement. I know it's hot. I care about *why* it was doing what it was doing, so I know if I can do without it.
  That's what the stack samples tell me.
  Just looking at a hot line isn't enough information.

I know that's more than you asked for, but the simple fact that you are taking stack samples and looking for a way to summarize them means you're really on the right track, IMO.
Good luck.

---

P.S. Don't you want to store *inclusive* counts on each node, as in:

```
root:17
  a:12
    e:4
    c:4
      d:2
  b:5
    c:2
      e:2
```

because that will tell you the cost (in the sense of potential savings) of each node. If you're concerned about "exclusive time", note [point 8 of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple recursive method that will create the tree. This can be easily adapted based in the methods that you will need.

```
def to_tree(data)
  tree =  data.inject([0,{}]) do |cont, element|
    if element.empty?
      cont[0] += 1
    else
      node = element.shift
      cont[1][node] ||= []
      cont[1][node] << element
    end

    cont
  end

  tree[1].map do |k, v|
    tree[1][k] = to_tree(v)
  end

  [tree[0],tree[1].sort{|a,b| b[1][0] <=> a[1][0]}]
end

def p_tree(node_tree, node_name='root', node_level=0)
  p "#{' '*node_level}#{node_name}:#{node_tree[0]}"
  node_tree[1].each do |node|
    p_tree(node[1], node[0], node_level + 1)
  end
end

samples = [
  %w[a],
  %w[a c],
  %w[a],
  %w[a],
  %w[b],
  %w[b],
  %w[a],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a c d],
  %w[a c d],
  %w[b],
  %w[b c e],
  %w[b c e],
  %w[a c],
  %w[a e],
  %w[a e]
]

p_tree(to_tree(samples))
```

The method that is currently printing the tree can be easily modified to create the tree object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my less-than-ideal solution. In my defense, it was crafted with changing input, so it first transforms to a data structure that was originally fed in:

```
PNode = Struct.new(:name,:time,:parent) do
  attr_writer :kids
  def kids; @kids||=[]; end
  def add( name, time=0 )
    self.class.new( name, time, self ).tap{ |n| kids << n }
  end
  def to_s(lv=0)
    [ "#{'..'*lv}#{name}:#{time}", *kids.map{|k| k.to_s(lv+1) } ].join("\n")
  end
end

module Enumerable
  def sum(init=0,method=:to_i)
    inject(init){ |sum,o| sum+o.send(method) }
  end
end

# Build a tree of calls
root = PNode.new('root',0)
samples.each do |callstack|
  n = root; last_index = callstack.length-1
  callstack.each_with_index do |name,i|
    n = n.add( name, i==last_index ? 1 : 0 )
  end
end

# Sum the tree values at each level
def top_down(nodes,lv=0,parent=nil)
  nodes.group_by(&:name).sort_by{ |name,ns|
    [ -ns.map(&:time).sum, name ]
  }.map{ |name,same_name_calls|
    self_time = same_name_calls.map(&:time).sum
    PNode.new(name,self_time,parent).tap do |x|
      x.kids = top_down( same_name_calls.map(&:kids).flatten, lv+1, x )
    end
  }
end

puts top_down(root.kids).map(&:to_s)
```